# .NET async Main method thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, clr

I am just wondering in an app without a `SynchronizationContext` (e.g. Console), how is `async static Main(args)` implemented. Is the start of the main method before any `await` a

1. Threadpool thread, where the CLR itself has a dedicated thread which queues `Main` call onto the threadpool and synchronously waits for it to finish?

   OR
2. Is it a dedicated starter thread, which gets compiled into a special state machine, to synchronously block the thread at each await. Or even maybe all `await`s get combined into one and the `main` thread waits for this combined task to complete?

Comment: It's really just syntactic sugar, when compiled, a normal Main method gets added that calls `Main(args).GetAwaiter().GetResult();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `async static Task Main` method really just generates an entry point like this:

```cs
public static void GeneratedEntryPoint(string[] args)
{
    Main(args).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

So just like a normal synchronous `Main` method, it starts in a thread with no synchronization context. That means any continuations are executed on thread-pool threads. But the initial thread (which will execute any code until the first `await` expression that needs to schedule a continuations) is not a thread-pool thread itself.

Comment: Perfect thanks, still not able to mark as accepted, will mark as accepted one it shows up. (2 day delay I think?)